# How to refer to a specific GPIO pin in an Arduino Uno using C code?

Tags: c, embedded, avr, gpio, atmega

I am trying to design a 4-bit adder. I've set my input and output ports but am not sure where to go from there.

My "B" input port is Port D, my "A" input port as well as my "Cin" is Port B, and my "S" output port as well as my "Cout" is Port C. I am having trouble figuring out how to isolate the individual ports (such as the carry ripple) and am pretty much out of ideas aside from nested if-statements.

My code is currently as follows:

```
#include <avr/io.h>//library used to access the pin addresses

int main () {
    DDRD &= ~(0b00111100);//B inputs
    DDRB &= ~(0b00011111);//Carry-in + A inputs
    DDRC |= 0b00011111;//Carry-out + S outputs
    while (1) {
        //PORTC |= PIND + PINB;
        //PORTC &= ~(PIND + PINB);
        if ((PIND & 0b00000000)&&(PINB & 0b00000000)) {
            PORTC |= 0b00000000;
            PORTC &= ~(0b00000000);
        }
        else if ((((PIND & 0b00000100)||(PIND & 0b00001000)||(PIND & 0b00010000)||(PIND & 0b00100000))&&(PINB & 0b00000000))||(((PINB & 0b00000100)||(PINB & 0b00001000)||(PINB & 0b00010000)||(PINB & 0b00100000))&&(PIND & 0b00000000)))
            PORTC |= 0b00000001;
            PORTC &= ~(0b11111110);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `PORTx` is the name of register for setting pin high-low (when configured as output).

Comment: How do I refer to that specific pin? For example, if I wanna perform a bitwise XOR on digital pin 4 located in D instead of the entire PIND.

Comment: First find where is pin 4 located. To do XOR or toggle pin, use xor operator with port register and your mask. I dont have the details what you want to achieve.

Comment: if you do 4 bits adder, why you have a carry in in DDRB?  the carry is just for result? 15 + 15 = 30 as max sum

Comment: The fact that the board is an Arduino Uno is largely irrelevant if you choose not to use the Arduino framework and libraries (https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/DigitalPins).  It is essentially then just a ATmega328P development board, and you will get better information by seeking generic ATmega resources rather then Arduino specific ones.  In fact, I would tag the question as such and probably remove the referece ot Arduino - it is largely irelevant.

Comment: I think you have over-specialised the question with discussion of your application, and even GPIO. It is unclear what you are asking.  Perhaps if you included your "nested if statements idea" it would be clear what it is you are trying to achieve.  Your code as it is is insufficient because it does not indicate what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: If you want something that makes abstract reference to individual pins, you could use the Arduino layers - they are inefficient but they at least give you a single-pin abstraction.  Otherwise you'll probably end up doing a lot of bit masking...

Comment: Yeah, are you programming this using the Arduino IDE?  If so, are you willing to use functions like `digitalRead` and `pinMode`?

Comment: I'm using Powershell but I wouldn't mind using those functions if they work for C

Comment: I'm guessing you are avoiding using a simple sum operator so you could study how an adder would be implemented with logic circuits? 
If simple sum operator `+` this is a problem o basically getting the numbers from the ports with bitmasks. If you want to use only the bit operators and,or,xor,not, etc, this will get a little more interesting. But to be honest the best way for studying hardware implementation with logic circuits is with a FPGA. I don't suppose you have access to one?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to refer to a specific pin/pins then it's relatively easy (assuming the registers are set as outputs):

For example, to isolate pin 4 on PORTD you do:

```
PORTD |= (1 << PIND4);
```

This will set pin 4 in PORTD to HIGH.

```
PORTD |= (1 << PIND4) | (1 << PIND5);
```

This will set pins 4 and 5 in PORTD to HIGH.

```
PORTD &= ~(1 << PIND4);
```

This will set pin 4 in PORTD to LOW.

```
PORTD &= ~(1 << PIND4) & ~(1 << (PIND5);
```

This will set pins 4 and 5 in PORTD to LOW.

You can also define a macro for the (1 << n) logic:

```
#define _BV(n) (1 << (n))
```

These tutorial have it all explained pretty well: http://maxembedded.com/2011/06/port-operations-in-avr/ and https://efundies.com/avr-bitwise-operations-in-c/.

If you go through the bitwise logic step by step on a sheet of paper it will become clearer!